# C# pass multiple strings to php webservice

Tags: c#, php, web-services

i'm trying to pass multiple strings to a function inside a php webservice but not sure how.
One string will be a name and the second string will be a list of addresses and I would like to use the webservice to upload them to a mysql database.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code in c# i have so far:

```
  string namelog = "testpass";
            com.look.retrievesdl det = new com.look.retrievesdl();
            det.Timeout = -1;
            string lists = det.retrieve(namelog);
            det.Timeout = -1;
            string[] addresses = lists.Split(',');
```

What i want to do is pass a hashtable as well as the string namelog to a php webservice but not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: What's your question? What code do you have so far?

Comment: this probably doesn't need to be tagged PHP either - an HTTP request looks the same regardless of the server language.. there is nothing specifically PHP about the question.

Comment: is `com.look.retrievesdl` the proxy class generated from the webservice? maybe if you show the WSDL we can help.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a hashtable to PHP using this form:

```
lines[]=Line1Test&lines[]=Line2Text
```

In this case webserver will receive an array of lines in $_GET. Is that what you want?